# Closing an external application with qt

Tags: c++, qt

Please how do i close an application i previously opened with `QDesktopServices::OpenURL` in qt c++.
Because i need to update text in a PDF i already opened outside my application at a point in time.

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::pdfFormat);
printer.setOutputFileName("file.pdf");
doc.print(&printer);  // doc is QTextDocument
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file.pdf"));
```

And also i would like to know the difference between `QDesktopServices::OpenURL` and `Qt::openUrlExternally` and basically when to use them.

Answer (score 6):

You can't close an external application opened by `QDesktopServices::OpenURL`. There is no such option, and this method provides no information about started process that could be used to close it.

You can use native C++ platform-dependent functions to determine the path of PDF viewer executable. Then you can use `QProcess` to launch it. So `kill()` and `terminate()` can be used to close the application.

`Qt::openUrlExternally` can be used in QML code, and `QDesktopServices::OpenURL` can be used in C++ code. That's the only difference. I've read `Qt::openUrlExternally` sources, it calls `QDesktopServices::OpenURL` internally.

Comment: Thanks. But since the file is already opened, i can't update its contents hence i would like to prompt the user to close it first. How do i test if the file is opened(that is `doc.print(&printer)` can't work.)